# Difference between final cell state and RNN output in LSTM Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, lstm, recurrent-neural-network

I am trying to understand LSTM in Tensorflow , I am doing simple classification using `tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` , which return two things , One is final_result of each cell and second is hidden state of only last cell , Now my confusion is if i am taking final output for next fully_connected layer then it's taking too much time and iterations(even 10000 iteration are not enough for it)  for decreasing the loss , while if i am taking final state output for next layer then its giving good result only in 500 iteration :

my data for classification is :

```
vocab_ = {'\xa0': 60, 'S': 26, 'W': 30, 'É': 62, 'Á': 61, 'ò': 75, 'ê': 71, 'õ': 77, 'ñ': 74, 'J': 17, 'o': 48, ',': 3, "'": 2, 'g': 40, 'Q': 24, 'ż': 87, 'B': 9, 'ç': 68, 'O': 22, 'N': 21, 'D': 11, 'd': 37, 'x': 57, 'q': 50, 'L': 19, 'z': 59, 'U': 28, 'F': 13, 'w': 56, 't': 53, 'h': 41, 'j': 43, '1': 6, 'r': 51, 'e': 38, 'K': 18, 'k': 44, 'ú': 80, 'a': 34, 'ü': 81, 'é': 70, 'I': 16, 'Y': 32, 'ì': 72, 'ó': 76, 'A': 8, 'c': 36, 'E': 12, 'i': 42, 'G': 14, 'à': 64, 'y': 58, 'V': 29, 'C': 10, 'X': 31, 'ä': 67, '0': 0, 'b': 35, 's': 52, '/': 5, 'n': 47, 'p': 49, 'ö': 78, 'ą': 82, ' ': 1, 'Ż': 86, 'l': 45, 'á': 65, 'ù': 79, ':': 7, 'u': 54, 'Z': 33, 'è': 69, 'Ś': 85, 'm': 46, '-': 4, 'ł': 83, 'T': 27, 'P': 23, 'ń': 84, 'R': 25, 'í': 73, 'ã': 66, 'ß': 63, 'v': 55, 'M': 20, 'H': 15, 'f': 39}


sequences=[[18, 41, 48, 54, 51, 58, 0, 0],[18, 41, 48, 54, 51, 58, 0, 0], [21, 34, 41, 34, 52, 0, 0, 0], [11, 34, 41, 38, 51, 0, 0, 0], [14, 38, 51, 40, 38, 52, 0, 0], [21, 34, 59, 34, 51, 42, 0, 0], [20, 34, 34, 45, 48, 54, 39, 0], [14, 38, 51, 40, 38, 52, 0, 0], [21, 34, 42, 39, 38, 41, 0, 0], [14, 54, 42, 51, 40, 54, 42, 52], [9, 34, 35, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0], [26, 34, 35, 35, 34, 40, 41, 0], [8, 53, 53, 42, 34, 0, 0, 0], [27, 34, 41, 34, 47, 0, 0, 0], [15, 34, 37, 37, 34, 37, 0, 0], [8, 52, 56, 34, 37, 0, 0, 0], [21, 34, 43, 43, 34, 51, 0, 0], [11, 34, 40, 41, 38, 51, 0, 0], [20, 34, 45, 48, 48, 39, 0, 0], [16, 52, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [8, 52, 40, 41, 34, 51, 0, 0], [21, 34, 37, 38, 51, 0, 0, 0], [14, 34, 35, 38, 51, 0, 0, 0], [8, 35, 35, 48, 54, 37, 0, 0], [20, 34, 34, 45, 48, 54, 39, 0], [33, 48, 40, 35, 58, 0, 0, 0], [26, 51, 48, 54, 51, 0, 0, 0], [9, 34, 41, 34, 51, 0, 0, 0], [20, 54, 52, 53, 34, 39, 34, 0], [15, 34, 47, 34, 47, 42, 34, 0], [11, 34, 41, 38, 51, 0, 0, 0], [27, 54, 46, 34, 0, 0, 0, 0], [21, 34, 41, 34, 52, 0, 0, 0], [26, 34, 45, 42, 35, 34, 0, 0], [26, 41, 34, 46, 48, 48, 47, 0]]


labels_x = [9, 0, 12, 4, 8, 12, 6, 1, 6, 7, 11, 14, 8, 4, 0, 5, 7, 12, 2, 5, 3, 9, 14, 1, 10, 12, 12, 14, 2, 2, 12, 13, 0, 2, 11]
```

First , If i take final output instead of state output then its taking more iteration and result is not good here is code :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

epoch=2

tf.reset_default_graph()

input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[None,None])

output_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[None,])

word_embedding = tf.get_variable('embedding',shape=[len(vocab_),250],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))

sequence_len= tf.count_nonzero(input_x,axis=-1)

with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:

    output,state_output=tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(150),tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(150),inputs=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embedding,input_x),sequence_length=sequence_len,dtype=tf.float32)


transpose_w=tf.transpose(output[0],[1,0,2])
transpose_r=tf.transpose(output[1],[1,0,2])

final_output= tf.concat([transpose_r[-1],transpose_w[-1]],axis=-1)

weights=tf.get_variable('weights',shape=[2*150,len(labels_x)],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))

bias = tf.get_variable('bias',shape=[len(labels_x)],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))

final_result = tf.matmul(final_output,weights) + bias

#normalization
prob=tf.nn.softmax(final_result)
pred=tf.argmax(prob,axis=-1)

#cross entropy
ce=tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=final_result,labels=output_y)
loss=tf.reduce_mean(ce)

#evaluate
acc=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast((tf.equal(tf.cast(pred,tf.int32),output_y)),tf.float32))

#train
train=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(epoch):
        for j in range(200):
            first,second,third,forth,fifth,_=sess.run([loss,prob,pred,final_result,acc,train],feed_dict={input_x:sequences,output_y:labels_x})



            print("Iteration {}th epoch  {}th loss {}  accuracy {} ".format(j,i,first,fifth))
```

output :

```
Iteration 0th epoch  0th loss 3.558173179626465  accuracy 0.02857142873108387 
Iteration 1th epoch  0th loss 3.556957960128784  accuracy 0.02857142873108387 
Iteration 2th epoch  0th loss 3.5557243824005127  accuracy 0.05714285746216774 

.
.
.
Iteration 197th epoch  1th loss 3.102834939956665  accuracy 0.20000000298023224 
Iteration 198th epoch  1th loss 3.1021459102630615  accuracy 0.20000000298023224 
Iteration 199th epoch  1th loss 3.101456880569458  accuracy 0.20000000298023224 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see after 400 iteration , result is not good only 0.20 accuracy  , Now if i take hidden state output instead of final output :

then code is :

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.contrib import rnn

epoch=2

tf.reset_default_graph()

input_x = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[None,None])
output_y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32,shape=[None,])

word_embedding = tf.get_variable('embedding',shape=[len(vocab_),250],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))

sequence_len= tf.count_nonzero(input_x,axis=-1)

with tf.variable_scope('encoder') as scope:
    output,state_output=tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(150),tf.nn.rnn_cell.LSTMCell(150),inputs=tf.nn.embedding_lookup(word_embedding,input_x),sequence_length=sequence_len,dtype=tf.float32)


transpose_w=tf.transpose(output[0],[1,0,2])
transpose_r=tf.transpose(output[1],[1,0,2])

state_out = tf.concat([state_output[0].c,state_output[1].c],axis=-1)
weights=tf.get_variable('weights',shape=[2*150,len(labels_x)],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))

bias = tf.get_variable('bias',shape=[len(labels_x)],dtype=tf.float32,initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer(-0.01,0.01))

final_result = tf.matmul(state_out,weights) + bias

#normalization
prob=tf.nn.softmax(final_result)
pred=tf.argmax(prob,axis=-1)

#cross entropy
ce=tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=final_result,labels=output_y)
loss=tf.reduce_mean(ce)


#evaluate
acc=tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast((tf.equal(tf.cast(pred,tf.int32),output_y)),tf.float32))

#train
train=tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss)


with tf.Session() as sess:

    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

    for i in range(epoch):
        for j in range(200):
            first,second,third,forth,fifth,_=sess.run([loss,prob,pred,final_result,acc,train],feed_dict={input_x:sequences,output_y:labels_x})
            print("Iteration {}th epoch  {}th loss {}  accuracy {} ".format(j,i,first,fifth))
```

and output is

```
Iteration 0th epoch  0th loss 3.557037830352783  accuracy 0.0 
Iteration 1th epoch  0th loss 3.553581476211548  accuracy 0.11428571492433548 
Iteration 2th epoch  0th loss 3.549212694168091  accuracy 0.17142857611179352 
Iteration 3th epoch  0th loss 3.5429491996765137  accuracy 0.2857142984867096 
.
.
.
.
.
Iteration 197th epoch  1th loss 0.19866235554218292  accuracy 0.8571428656578064 
Iteration 198th epoch  1th loss 0.19868074357509613  accuracy 0.8571428656578064 
Iteration 199th epoch  1th loss 0.19868910312652588  accuracy 0.8571428656578064 

Process finished with exit code 0
```

As you can see it is giving good accuracy under same iterations , But if you look at different github LSTM classification code or any tutorial , you will find everyone is taking final output instead of last state output , Am i doing any mistake while taking final output that's why i am not getting good result ? Please guide me ,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete answer but here I can point out some points that may help you,

> I am doing simple classification using tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn
>   , which return two things , One is final_result of each cell and
>   second is hidden state of only last cell

This is correct. But when you are using LSTM, according to [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/dynamic_rnn), 
output of `tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn` is `pair (outputs, state)` where `state` is a `LSTMStateTuple` containing `hidden state` and `cell state` of your last cell given by the `sequence_length` argument for each of the `example` in the `batch`.

Given that you want to categorize a sequence (not each word), the last state of a lstm contains all the previous state's intuitions and last state's (according to `sequence length`) output. So using only the cell state is `ok` because from here you will get all the intuitions of the previous state of the sequence. That's why it is working well.

here, from `pair (outputs, state)`, `output` contains all the outputs of the cell. Remember you padded each of the sequences with `0` to make the size of the sequence same. the output of `t^th` cell is empty if `t` is greater than the `sequence length` of a particular example, but the cell state is copied to the next cell from the previous cell if `t` is greater than the `sequence length`.

Now if you take the `output` of the LSTM, you will be taking all the cell's output including the padded zero cells which should be discarded. **This might create the problem**.

Comment: Thank you for that answer , I wanted to know when i will use state output and when i should use output for next layer ? What i got is when i need to do something with each word in sequence then output will be best but if i need to do only with sequence then state is good ?

Comment: yes. But i don't know for sure as it may vary from problem to problem. see the youtube video, https://m.youtube.com/watch?t=1565s&v=pzOzmxCR37I. they used output and it works for them. In seq2seq model they also works with  hidden layer. where on the other hand I also woked with some sentiment analysis where cell state just works fine. I guess you at least have to try once which state(hidden or cell) works for you. but if you are working with GRU you don't have to think about this.

Comment: @why i don't have to worry about GRU ? because it only return output ?

Comment: yea you are right. in GRU cell state and hidden state is same. But i kind of like LSTM. works better with large data.